# Align a Pin-it Button along with some text on the same line with css

Tags: html, css

I'm really stumped and hoping for a bit of css help.

I have a pin it button that I'd like to display, along with some text.  I'd like them to be on the same line and lined up, if you will both horizontally & vertically, with some space between (enough space so they look nice)

Thank-you in advance .. Alison   (http://www.veggiesbycandlelight.com)

https://jsfiddle.net/alisonrost/9mwg5pvh/1/

```
<div class="recipesharing">
<div>
<img class="pintherecipe" style="display:inline;" />
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" data-pin-tall="true" data-pin-round="true" data-pin-save="false"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_round_red_32.png" /></a><p.id>Pin For Later</p.id>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `vertical-algin` property for image

Here [Fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mwg5pvh/2/)

```
img {vertical-align: middle;margin-right:5px;}
```

Comment: Thank-you so much!

Comment: I added the updated Fiddle code to a test post on my site and the end result is a bit different.  Not sure what I may be missing?  http://www.veggiesbycandlelight.com/alison-test-pinning/

Comment: @ali.rost update this code `.PIN_1467603120320_button_pin.PIN_1467603120320_round.PIN_1467603120320_tall {
    vertical-align: bottom;}` if this not work then `.PIN_1467603120320_button_pin.PIN_1467603120320_round.PIN_1467603120320_tall {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;}`

Comment: and your fiddle is a little bit different.

Comment: Thank-you.  Sadly .. neither worked.  (I should note I added them as part of the site's css).  Also you were right about the fiddle .. I made them match.

Comment: @ali.rost `span.PIN_1467689791666_button_pin.PIN_1467689791666_round.PIN_1467689791666_tall {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
}` this code is working fine in inspect element on your website.

`.PIN_1467689791666_button_pin` this class `vertical-align` property is set at `baseline` try to change this to `bottom` the code is in style tag

Answer (score 0):

Add to `img {vertical-align: middle;}` and also to `p {margin-left: 8px;}` and this will help you.

Comment: Thank-you for taking the time to look at the issue and respond

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:middle` to `a` and also some `padding-right:10px;`

```
div a{
      display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;
       padding-right:10px
    }
```